# The covariance of 2 independent and identically distributed

Tags: random-variable, covariance, error

I am currently researching a paper and they have the following set-up:

"
$(\epsilon_{1}, \epsilon_{2})iid \sim N(\mu, \xi)$. captures the collective biases that in-vestors may have about d, is captured by $\mu=(c_{1}, c_{2})$ and the covariance structure of the noisy signals is captured by $\xi=(\sigma_{1}^{2},\sigma_{2}^{2}, \sigma_{12})$. "

I epsilon 1 and 2 are noisy signals from the model. **My question is**: if the 2 random variables are independent, wouldn't that mean that the covariance between them is equal to 0?

Thank you

Comment: I believe you misinterpret the notation.  The clue is in "$\mu=(c_1,c_2),$" which manifestly exhibits $\mu$ as a *vector,* whence $\xi$ must be a ($2\times 2$) vector.

Comment: Are $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ time series?  There is some missing context here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What they mean is that if you draw $n$ samples of 2-tuples $\epsilon_i=(\epsilon_{i1},\epsilon_{i2})$ with $i>0$, then all $\epsilon_i$ 2-tuples (mutually) independent and follow the bivariate Normal distribution.

So $\epsilon_i=(\epsilon_{i1},\epsilon_{i2})$ and $\epsilon_j=(\epsilon_{j1},\epsilon_{j2})$ are always independent for $i\neq j$. But for each fixed $i$ their components, $\epsilon_{i1}$ and $\epsilon_{i2}$ , are not mutually independent and follow the covariance structure outlined above.

So, following the same distribution does not mean they are dependent. Dependence is meant that any realization of $\epsilon_i$ does not change the statistical properties of another sample draw $\epsilon_j$. They still follow the same identical distribution.